# Counter-Example for $f$ unbounded, $f$ continuous at $s$, and $\alpha(x)=I(x-s)$ such that $\int_a^b f \,d\alpha \neq f(s)$ (Rudin Thm 6.15)

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I'm reading Theorem 6.15 in Baby Rudin, which states that:

**Theorem 6.15:** If $a<s<b$, $f$ is **bounded** on $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous at $s$, and $\alpha(x)=I(x-s)$, then 
$$\int_a^b f \,d\alpha = f(s)$$
where $I$ is the unit step function defined by
$$I(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $(x \leq 0)$} \\
1, & \text{if $(x > 0)$ .}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

In case it is unclear, the integral above is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

I'm trying to think of an example where $f$ is **unbounded** on $[a,b]$ so that $\int_a^b f \,d\alpha \neq f(s)$, but I'm having a lot of trouble coming up with one.

Comment: I imagine the bounded requirement is just a technicality that ensures that the integral exists. In this case, since $f$ is continuous at $s$, and $\alpha$ is constant on any interval not including $s$, then I think the bounded is superfluous.

Comment: How does the proof use boundedness?

Comment: @IgorRivin: I've read Rudin's proof several times and I can't find where he uses boundedness. His proof is this. Consider the partitions $P=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ where $x_0=a$ and $x_1 = s < x_2 < x_3 = b$. Then $U(P,f,\alpha)=M_2$ and $L(P,f,\alpha)=m_2$. Since $f$ is continuous at $s$, we see that $M_2$ and $m_2$ converge to $f(s)$ as $x_2 \rightarrow s$.

Comment: This is completely consistent with @copper.hat's commentary...